bot.polling(none_stop=True) ошибка
помогите решить ошибку пожалуйста!
PS C:\Users\pc> & C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/pc/Desktop/tg-bot/tg-bot/tg-bot2/main.py
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\tg-bot\tg-bot\tg-bot2\main.py", line 43
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after function definition on line 41

сам код
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('***********')



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('baza.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()


    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(50)')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Купить голду')
    markup.row(btn4)
    btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('Пополнить баланс')
    markup.row(btn5)
    btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('Вывод')
    markup.row(btn6)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет {message.from_user.first_name}!\n▶️ Для продолжения выбери нужную команду на клавиатуре\n‍♂️ Если есть дополнительные вопросы по поводу бота, обратитесь в Тех.Поддержку\n Курс: 0.63', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_message_handler(message,cef)

def cef (message):
    if message.text == 'Купить голду':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сначало пополните балнас!')
    elif message.text == 'Пополнить баланс':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'выстови скин!')



@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_phot(message):

bot.polling(none_stop=True)


Что непонятно в тексте ошибки? Предельно ясно написано в чем проблема.
